# Laravel: Importing Null Values in the database table from CSV file Upload

Tags: excel, laravel, csv, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to upload data from a csv file. When the data is imported to the database table, the values are NULL. My CSV file has value.

I did this process by installing Maatwebsite\Excel.

my code

```
class Template extends Model
{
    protected   $fillable = ['Origin', 'OriginState', 'Destination' , 'DestinationState' , 'Carrier', 'Car' , 'Buy', 
                              'Carbon', 'DepotFrom', 'DepotTo', 'OriginType', 'DestinationType'
                            ,'GoodsAllowed', 'NonRunners', 'ETA',  'Comments', 'Disabled' ];
}



  public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('uploadRates')) {
            $path = $request->file('uploadRates')->getRealPath();
            $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();

            if (!empty($data) && $data->count()) {
                foreach ($data as   $value) {
                    $arr[] = ['Origin' => $value->Origin,
                              'OriginState' => $value->OriginState,
                              'Destination' => $value->Destination,
                              'DestinationState' => $value->DestinationState,
                              'Carrier' => $value->Carrier,
                              'Car' => $value->Car,
                              'Buy' => $value->Buy,
                              'Carbon' => $value->Carbon,
                              'DepotFrom' => $value->DepotFrom,
                              'DepotTo' => $value->DepotTo,
                              'OriginType' => $value->OriginType,
                              'DestinationType' => $value->DestinationType,
                              'GoodsAllowed' => $value->GoodsAllowed,
                              'NonRunners' => $value->NonRunners,
                              'ETA' => $value->ETA,
                              'Comments' => $value->Comments,
                              'Disabled' => $value->Disabled,

                             ];
                }
                if (!empty($arr)) {
                    DB::table('template')->insert($arr);
                    return "Success";
                }
            }
        }
        dd('Requested file has no Data inside.');
    }
```

and my CSV data:

**Origin,OriginState,Destination,DestinationState,Carrier,Car,Buy,Carbon,DepotFrom,DepotTo,OriginType,DestinationType,GoodsAllowed,NonRunners,ETA,Comments,Disabled**

> Adelaide,SA,Melbourne,VIC,A1 Auto
>   Transporter,Car,250,0,0,0,Depot,Depot,0,0,5,,0
>   Adelaide,SA,Canberra,ACT,A1 Auto
>   Transporter,Car,609.0909091,0,0,0,Depot,Depot,0,0,7,,0
>   Adelaide,SA,Sydney,NSW,A1 Auto
>   Transporter,Car,409.0909091,0,0,0,Depot,Depot,0,0,7,,0
>   Adelaide,SA,Brisbane,QLD,A1 Auto
>   Transporter,Car,727.2727273,0,0,0,Depot,Depot,0,0,8,,0
>   Adelaide,SA,Townsville,QLD,A1 Auto
>   Transporter,Car,1428.181818,0,0,0,Depot,Depot,0,0,12,,0
>   Adelaide,SA,Cairns,QLD,A1 Auto
>   Transporter,Car,1491.818182,0,0,0,Depot,Depot,0,0,14,,0

my database screeshot:
[image]

dd($data) output:

```
RowCollection {#787 ▼
  #heading: array:17 [▼
    0 => "origin"
    1 => "originstate"
    2 => "destination"
    3 => "destinationstate"
    4 => "carrier"
    5 => "car"
    6 => "buy"
    7 => "carbon"
    8 => "depotfrom"
    9 => "depotto"
    10 => "origintype"
    11 => "destinationtype"
    12 => "goodsallowed"
    13 => "nonrunners"
    14 => "eta"
    15 => "comments"
    16 => "disabled"
  ]
  #title: "Worksheet"
  #items: array:18 [▼
    0 => CellCollection {#790 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:17 [▼
        "origin" => "Adelaide"
        "originstate" => "SA"
        "destination" => "Melbourne"
        "destinationstate" => "VIC"
        "carrier" => "A1 Auto Transporter"
        "car" => "Car"
        "buy" => 250.0
        "carbon" => 0.0
        "depotfrom" => 0.0
        "depotto" => 0.0
        "origintype" => "Depot"
        "destinationtype" => "Depot"
        "goodsallowed" => 0.0
        "nonrunners" => 0.0
        "eta" => 5.0
        "comments" => null
        "disabled" => 0.0
      ]
    }
    1 => CellCollection {#792 ▶}
    2 => CellCollection {#794 ▶}
    3 => CellCollection {#796 ▶}
    4 => CellCollection {#798 ▶}
    5 => CellCollection {#800 ▶}
    6 => CellCollection {#802 ▶}
    7 => CellCollection {#804 ▶}
    8 => CellCollection {#806 ▶}
    9 => CellCollection {#808 ▶}
    10 => CellCollection {#810 ▶}
    11 => CellCollection {#812 ▶}
    12 => CellCollection {#814 ▶}
    13 => CellCollection {#816 ▶}
    14 => CellCollection {#818 ▶}
    15 => CellCollection {#820 ▶}
    16 => CellCollection {#822 ▶}
    17 => CellCollection {#824 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because when you use first row headings as attributes, they are slugged.

This means that `Origin` will be `$value->origin`.

If you want to use your original attributes then you can change the setting in your excel.php config under `import.heading` to `orginal`.

**EDIT: I just realised from your comments that you have startRow in your config set to 2. Change that to 1.**

Comment: I changed it to original in the excel.php `'import'  => [orginal' => 'slugged', 'startRow' => 2,....];` but the output is still the same. Null values

Comment: i also tried removing the header (1st row from the csv file) but still I had the same results. Null Values.

Comment: You will be changing your config to be ```'import' => ['heading' => 'original', 'startRow'...```

Comment: well I did that too but has same problem. Null data imported.   `'heading'                 => 'original',`

Comment: Does the value exist in the code? eg. ```dd($value->origin);``` or ```dd($value->Origin);```

Comment: i checked the value and it comes null. and thats why i get the null values in the database table.

Comment: what about ```dd($value);```?

Comment: i got some values. for example `'Origin' => $value->Origin`  the output shows me `adelaide" => "Canberra`

Comment: Do you actually have a heading row in there? With Origin, etc?

Comment: yes, i have the excel (csv file) open in front of me. I have my first row (with Origin, OriginState, Destination, .....) and on the second line i have the data

Comment: hey, I saw the edit: post just now. I have changed it to 1, but still not working

Comment: So you should be able to get the values with ```$value->origin, $value->originstate``` etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185527/discussion-between-user10345537-and-cugreen).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($data) && $data->count()) {
            foreach ($data as   $value) {
                Template::create(
                       ['Origin' => $value->origin,
                          'OriginState' => $value->origin,
                          'Destination' => $value->destination,
                          'DestinationState' => $value->destinationstate,
                          'Carrier' => $value->$value->carrier,
                           ...
                           ...

                         ]
                );
            }
 }
```

// do not forget add $fillable attributes in Template model

`protected $fillable = ['Origin', 'Destination', ....]`

Comment: i have set my code according to your suggestion, but  I am getting an error. the error is `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'` .And yes, I have `protected $fillable` in my model

Comment: I changed ； to the end of ）， fix it and try again

Comment: I tried the code again, now i am getting this error `Undefined offset: 0` . I remembered this error because I was getting the same error earlier

Comment: dd（$data）  paste your output

Comment: Hey, any luck?? I am trying and i am getting the same error offser: 0. error

Answer (score 0):

Quite unfortunate I encountered the same issue and wasted a lot of time troubleshooting while the solution is quite simple.
This issue is a result of Laravel Excel trying to import to empty rows at the end of your file. To solve this you can do a check if the row has actual values before proceeding with the import. Or you can change the config to ignore empty rows  [https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/config/excel.php#L100](http://%20https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/config/excel.php#L100)